# Append to Excel from Access using VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

With this particular problem I can’t get the code to append the exported data from Access to Excel. I have created an simple Access database with some data shown on a form. After that it is possible to export the shown record to Excel using the code.

So far so good. But when I export the next record it overwrites the previous exported data on row one in Excel. I want the code to append to the next row and so on.

I have found some topics on how to append with “ActiveCell.Value” and “ActiveCell.Offset” but my knowledge is too limited to get it to work with the code. The moment I think I got it, VBE comes with errors. It seems I can't figure this out.

```
Private Sub Command15_Click()
Dim oExcel          As Object
Dim oExcelWrkBk     As Object
Dim oExcelWrSht     As Object
Dim bExcelOpened    As Boolean

'Start Excel
On Error Resume Next
Set oExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")    'Bind to existing instance of Excel
If Err.Number <> 0 Then    'Could not get instance of Excel, so create a new one
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
    bExcelOpened = False
Else    'Excel was already running
    bExcelOpened = True
End If
On Error GoTo Error_Handler
oExcel.ScreenUpdating = False
oExcel.Visible = False   'Keep Excel hidden until we are done with our manipulation
'Set oExcelWrkBk = oExcel.Workbooks.Add()    'Start a new workbook
Set oExcelWrkBk = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx")     'Open an existing Excel file
Set oExcelWrSht = oExcelWrkBk.Sheets(1) 'which worksheet to work with

'Start copying over your form values to the Excel Spreadsheet
'Cells(8, 3) = 8th row, 3rd column
oExcelWrSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Me.1
oExcelWrSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Me.2
oExcelWrSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Me.3
oExcelWrSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Me.4
oExcelWrSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Me.5
oExcelWrSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Me.6
oExcelWrSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Me.7
oExcelWrSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Me.8
oExcelWrSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Me.9
'... and so on ...

oExcelWrSht.Range("A1").Select  'Return to the top of the page

'    oExcelWrkBk.Close True, sFileName 'Save and close the generated workbook
'    'Close excel if is wasn't originally running
'    If bExcelOpened = False Then
'        oExcel.Quit
'    End If Error_Handler_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
oExcel.Visible = True   'Make excel visible to the user
Set oExcelWrSht = Nothing
Set oExcelWrkBk = Nothing
oExcel.ScreenUpdating = True
Set oExcel = Nothing
Exit Sub Error_Handler:
MsgBox "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
       "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
       "Error Source: Export2XLS" & vbCrLf & _
       "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
       , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
Resume Error_Handler_Exit End Sub
```

Comment: If you are using a database, why would you want to append the record to Excel? Why not store the records in Access (which is what a database is for) and have Excel pull the records it needs from the database?

Comment: So every time you run this surely it will just set the values of the 10th row? I'm missing the attempt where you try and move it to the next row down?

Comment: @jkpieterse: How can I achieve this? Can you push me into the right direction?

Comment: @Tim Edwards: Sorry, exactly the code writes the exported data to row 10. I tried to achieve to go to the next row using “ActiveCell.Value” and “ActiveCell.Offset” (not shown in the code), but every time I tried I got errors from VBE (I tried for 3 days straight, but with no luck). So I reverted back to the point where the code works.

Comment: So for getting the next row down you need to use something like `Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "My Value"` but change 10 to be whichever column you want.

Comment: @jkpieterse has a good point though. Why not use `docmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO MyTable (Column1, Column2, Column3) SELECT " & chr(34) & "Hello" & chr(34) & ", " & chr(34) & "World" & chr(34) & ", " & chr(34) & "This is a test" & chr(34)` to insert into a table (assuming you've not already bound your form) and then `docmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport,,"MyTable","C:\test.xlsx",True` to export it.

Comment: @Tim Edwards: I have changed the code according as you suggested. Is this the right way to achieve what I want? (sorry for my incompetence, I’m not a Programmer and I don’t understand everything yet).

Comment: The "right" way is debatable. But what you've put isn't quite right as that will put everything in the 10th column. What you need is: `    oExcelWrSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Me.1
    oExcelWrSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Me.2
    oExcelWrSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Me.3` if I understand your form correctly.

Comment: @ Tim Edwards: I changed the code again in the initial post. I’ve just tried the code in Access to export the data from a record to Excel, but then I receive an error:  “The following error has occurred. Error number: 424, Error source: Export2XLS, Error description: Object required.” This is the same error  which I received for the past 3 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried this and no problems so assuming you have a reference to the right excel library can you see if this works?

```
Sub Test()
Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
Dim oExcelWrkBk As Excel.Workbook
Dim oExcelWrSht As Excel.Worksheet

'Start Excel
On Error Resume Next
Set oExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Else
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
End If

oExcel.ScreenUpdating = False
oExcel.Visible = False 'This is false by default anyway

Set oExcelWrkBk = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx")
Set oExcelWrSht = oExcelWrkBk.Sheets(1)

oExcelWrSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "Test1"
oExcelWrSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "Test2"
oExcelWrSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "Test3"

oExcelWrSht.Range("A1").Select

oExcelWrkBk.Save

oExcel.ScreenUpdating = True
oExcel.Visible = True

Exit_Point:
Set oExcelWrSht = Nothing
Set oExcelWrkBk = Nothing
Set oExcel = Nothing
Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
MsgBox Err & " - " & Err.Description
GoTo Exit_Point
End Sub
```

Comment: The code works spot on! Thank you very much. I had some problems with some library references such as the Excel Object Library and Microsoft Form 2.0. I added these and the errors where gone.
One question though; after the data is exported to Excel, is it possible that the opened Excel file just saves automatically, without closing the Excel file?

Comment: Yes, I'll add that in.

Comment: Again, thank you for helping me out with my very limited VBA knowledge. The code does exactly what I want it to do.

Comment: Cool. If you feel like I've sufficiently solved your issue then you could mark it as the answer using the tick. Just saying as you're a new user so you may be unaware. ;)